# Having hard time coding the react native search function

Tags: react-native, uisearchbar

List Component consist of search bar.

```
export default class List extends Component {
  state = {
    search : '',
    data: ''
  };

  updateSearch = childData => {
    this.setState({ data: childData })
  };

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Numeric search and company name"
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
          value={search}
          platform='ios'
          containerStyle={styles.searchContainer}
          ref={search => this.search = search}
        />
        <ListItem /> // ListItem Component
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Below is ListItem Component consist of, the Data and SectionList

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: '#',
    data: ['#01-K1 - 6OZ Expresso Bar'],
  },
  {
    title: 'A',
    data: ['#32-01A - Abu Dhabi Chamber of Commerce & industry', '#25-06 - Amann Girrbach Asia Pte Ltd', '#30-02 - Agence France Presse Pte Ltd'],
  },
  {
    title: 'B',
    data: ['#09-01 - Blue Leaf Energy Asia Pte Ltd'],
  },


function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

sendData = () => {
  this.props.updateSearch({data})
}

export default class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <SectionList
            sections={DATA}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
              <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>

    )
  }
}
```

[image: Here's how the App look like]

So when a user search for Alphabet or a numeric number the app will display what they are searching for with the data given.I used Section List to achieve as the displayed image and react-native-element for the search Bar

Comment: so what is the problem you are getting

Comment: @Gaurav Roy I have a hard time coding the search bar functionality to display what's the user input in the search bar.